# C# Create Json Class with Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have this .json file I would like to create a class with dictionary. 
Below you will find the class. 
I would like to work with the dictionary. 
Does anyone know how I would have to rebuild the class and how I can then read the .json file?

---

```
{
    { "Schlagwortmaskname": "Verpackungstisch"}
      "Schlagwort": [
        {
          "Name": "Fertigungsauftrag",
          "Wert": "4594"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Kundenauftrag",
          "Wert": "Smith"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Produktname",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Artikelnummer",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Seriennummer",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Kunde",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Endkunde",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Musterbild",
          "Wert": "1"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Kommentar",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Repair Artikelnummer",
          "Wert": "Jones "
        },
        {
          "Name": "Erstellt am",
          "Wert": "10.12.2012 15:15:15"
        }
      ]
    }
```

---

```
 public class Informationen
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Wert { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string Schlagwortmaskname { get; set; }        
        public IList<Informationen> Informationen { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, to start with... you appear to have a nested object with no key... Beyond that, would you be satisfies with an intermediate JSON-specific representation which you could then transform to/from a dictionary approach? Note that `Dictionary<,>` doesn't preserve ordering, which means you wouldn't be able to serialize again without potentially reordering in the JSON.

Comment: Yes, that knows. Forgiveness. Unfortunately, I no longer knew how I had to make that only a string comes out `{ "Schlagwortmaskname": "Verpackungstisch"}` .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... do you mean the question doesn't show your actual JSON, or that you didn't know how to include it in the question properly?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the .json is not correct because of this line  `{ "Schlagwortmaskname": "Verpackungstisch"}` 
This line should only do `public string Schlagwortmaskname { get; set; }`

Comment: So why not update the question to show the *correct* JSON? (And ideally fewer elements or `Informationen` - we don't need all of those to understand the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var dictionary = values.Schlagwort.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y.Wert);
}

public class Informationen
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Wert { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Schlagwortmaskname { get; set; }
    public IList<Informationen> Schlagwort { get; set; }
}
```

Note that, as Jon Skeet pointed out, you will not be able to serialize again back to JSON. I don't really see the benefit of using a `Dictionary` over a model. But this way, you have your normal model and a dictionary you can work with. Otherwise you will have to write your own deserializer to make this work.

Lastly, your JSON is not valid. Fix it like this:

```
{
    "Schlagwortmaskname": "Verpackungstisch",
    "Schlagwort": [{
        "Name": "Fertigungsauftrag",
        "Wert": "4594"
    }, {
        "Name": "Kundenauftrag",
        "Wert": "Smith"
    }, {
        "Name": "Produktname",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Artikelnummer",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Seriennummer",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Kunde",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Endkunde",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Musterbild",
        "Wert": "1"
    }, {
        "Name": "Kommentar",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Repair Artikelnummer",
        "Wert": "Jones "
    }, {
        "Name": "Erstellt am",
        "Wert": "10.12.2012 15:15:15"
    }]
}
```